# Pipenv uses the wrong lib directory

Tags: pipenv, pyenv

I have a project using Python 3.10.4, i. e., the Pipfile has,

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.10.4"
```

I installed Python 3.10.4 using `pyenv install 3.10.4` and now `pyenv versions` returns,

```
* system (set by /home/username/.config/pyenv/version)
  3.10.4
```

Now when I run `pipenv install` I get,

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /home/username/.config/pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3 (3.10.4) to create virtualenv…
⠋created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 82ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-2ZeatEXR, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, pkg_resources==0.0.0, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.34.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Virtualenv location: /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-2ZeatEXR
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
  from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

The line `Using /home/username/.config/pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3 (3.10.4)` indicates that `pipenv` has found the right Python version and is using it to create the virtual environment but then when creating the lock file, observe that it uses the lib: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py` directory is of the system installation. Which then causes the error since the system's lib is for Python 3.9.

Maybe this is a bug or maybe I have missed some config. Could someone see what is going wrong here?